# PHP Ошибка при чтении файлов в директории

Tags: php

Залил на сервер клиента проект (Srv: Ubuntu 11.10, Apache22, nginx, php5.3)
Примерный код:

```
if($_SESSION && $_SESSION['user']) {    //Не думаю, что данный блок подобное вызывает
    $OUser = $_SESSION['user'];
    $user = json_encode($json);
    $json = array(
    'srvr'  => array(
            't' => get_server_time()    
        ),
    'usr'   =>array(
            'l'         =>  $OUser->login,
            'i18n'      =>  $OUser->lang
        )
    );
}


if ($dirname = opendir("../sites/" . $dir . "/js/")) {
        while (($file = readdir($dirname)) != false) {
        $path = $dir;
        if (is_dir($file) || $file == "." || $file == ".." || $file[strlen($file) - 1] == "~")
            continue;
        else 
            $js .= file_get_contents("../sites/" . $path . "/js/" . $file); 
    }
    closedir($dirname);
}

Header('Content-type: text/javascript'); 
echo $js . 'var sttng=' . json_encode($json);
```

В результате работы скрипта, я получаю между $js и var sttng примерно такую строку, которой там не должно быть:

```
���Kate Swap File-Version 1.0SW������"I����������ESR����������I����������ESR���������ESR���������ESR���������ESR���������ESR���������ESR����������ESU���Evar
```

Что это ?
Я думаю грешить на функцию file_get_contents() .... хотя на моем сервере (Gentoo 11.0, Yaws, nginx) такого не наблюдается :(

Не пойму что и откуда.... судя по всему - какой-то бэкап какого-то файла.... но какого и какого хрена он появляется - с трудом понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, разребся, это какой-то непонятно как генерируемый файл непонятно для чего и зачем (ДУмаю, что trumbs в Мастдае для этого же)... так вот, его просто тупо необходимо удалять, либо пропускать. Вобщем, добавил в условие, что чтение файлов, которые начинаются с "." запрещено :)

Answer (score 1):

Kate - текстовый редактор. под кеды. видимо ваш клиент им пользуется что бы посмотреть код) свап - ну это понятно) vim  так же оставляет за собой свап файлов ~filename.  сервер на убунте 11.10 да еще и с кдешным редактором - клева...))